# Using any input number to come up with an output number between 1 and X

Tags: calculus

I'm working on a way to load-balance a few different servers, but need help coming up with the math to do so. Lets say I have these random input numbers:

```
2353242
-4346323
43
64323
7544423
```

And just from an input number, I want to somehow get an output number between 1 and X.

So lets say if I were to run this function over a 1,000,000 random numbers, and that I want the output numbers to be between 1 and 5. Ideally, the numbers would roughly come close to:

```
200,000 input numbers would output 1
200,000 input numbers would output 2
200,000 input numbers would output 3
200,000 input numbers would output 4
200,000 input numbers would output 5
```

I'm not looking for just a random function to find between 1 and X, but a way to ALWAYS get the same output number with the same input number. The size of the input number is unknown, but the output number is always between 1 and X, X being the highest output number possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is take your number and find its remainder modulo $X$. It's the same as doing long division by $X$ and taking the remainder. This would give you a number between $0$ and $X - 1$, so just add $1$ to the output to get a number between $1$ and $X$. In code, you would write i % X where input is your i variable. As long as your input is just a random number, this will equally distribute the probability of your output.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would to use $(X \% 5)+1$, the remainder on division by $5$ (plus $1$ to get the range $1-5$ instead of $0-4$). If you don't like the regularity because one remainder is more likely than another, you could hash $X$ before taking the remainder.